# Unable to retrieve data from Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making my first app using Firebase database. I was able to access the database before, but then I updated my SDKs and couldn't access the Firebase database. This is the function I use

```
notedatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mrootDatabaseReference = notedatabase.getReference();
DatabaseReference firstchildref =mrootDatabaseReference.child(initpath);
```

When I run this it gives getserviceinstance failed error. When I try to debug the program the error states `notedatabase= null`. I have also changed the rules of my database. How do I fix this?

Sorry, this is my first time asking questions here, if I've left any information out kindly let me know. Thank you.

**EDIT :** The App works fine now I tried using

`String initpath = intent.getExtras().getString("initpath","");
databaseref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
final DatabaseReference numberofsubjectsRef = databaseref.child(initpath);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.   More details on see an [official link.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

```
    DatabaseReference databaseTracks;

    List<Track> tracks;

 databaseTracks = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tracks").child(intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.ARTIST_ID));



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseTracks.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                tracks.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Track track = postSnapshot.getValue(Track.class);
                    tracks.add(track);
                }
                TrackList trackListAdapter = new TrackList(ArtistActivity.this, tracks);
                listViewTracks.setAdapter(trackListAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay as you are posting it for first time please make sure this things you have done correctly before making an firebase messaging app using realtime database.

1) you have created a project in firebase and added you project name and package correctly.
 [image]

2)If in your firebase project rules(as above image) have been defined make sure to provide rules in place of Null it should be true, if you have not opted for any firebase authentication of firebase UI implementation.

3)your Initpath for child should be always same for accessing the same thread of message.